# unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \n<!d... @2:4)

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, maven-publish

I'm tryin to publish my Gradle projects on maven, via `maven-publish` plugin.

I set my Gradle script as follow
`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
apply<MavenPublishPlugin>()

publishing {
  publications.withType<MavenPublication> {

    artifact(javaDocsJar)
    artifact(sourcesJar)

    pom {
      name.set(c.name)
      description.set(c.description)
      url.set(c.siteUrl)
      scm {
        url.set(c.scmUrl)
        connection.set("scm:git:${c.scmConnection}")
        developerConnection.set("scm:git:${c.scmDevConnection}")
      }
    }
  }
  repositories {
    val target = c.organization.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() } ?: c.username
    maven("https://bintray.com/$target/${c.repo}/") {
      credentials {
        username = c.username
        password = c.apiKey
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After this I run `./gradlew publish`, and it starts to upload jars/aar/pom etc, but when it comes to **maven-metadata.xml** I got the following exception.

I tried on a Kotlin multiplatform project, on a java one ( mixed plain java/kotlin modules and Android ), on Android Studio 4.0, on IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1.1, on JDK 1.8, on JDK 14, with plain `maven-publish` plugin and with [this plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin). I really don't know what to try.
I already tried to exclude maven and plexus packages from Robolectric implementation, which is often problematic...

[**Kotlin multiplatform project here!**](https://github.com/4face-studi0/Assert4K)

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishPluginMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'pluginMaven' to repository 'maven'
   > org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \n<!d... @2:4) 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':util:util-gradle:publishPluginMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Failed to publish publication 'pluginMaven' to repository 'maven'
        at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.doPublish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \n<!d... @2:4) 
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.lambda$readExistingMetadata$1(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:139)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:113)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$10.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:221)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$10.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:213)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.readExistingMetadata(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.getExistingVersioning(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.createMetadata(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenRemotePublisher.publish(MavenRemotePublisher.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.ValidatingMavenPublisher.publish(ValidatingMavenPublisher.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository$1.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:37)
        ... 94 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \n<!d... @2:4) 
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1790)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1698)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1317)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1193)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1122)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1151)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.lambda$readExistingMetadata$1(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:137)
        ... 113 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I mistakingly used bintray pull repository name instead of push-name.

The correct push-name is `https://api.bintray.com/maven/$organization/$repository/$project/`.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: If you inspect the logs carefully, even in this case:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \n<!d... @2:4) 
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1790)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1698)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1317)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1193)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1122)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:1151)
        at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.lambda$readExistingMetadata$1(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:137)
```

you will notice, that gradle is trying to fetch data from maven repository, and it expects several XMLs to be provided (reposiotory definition, transitive dependencies `pom.xml` file e.t.c.).

The problem is that gradle tried to fetch this data from the server, and it did, but it failed to parse it.

This can happen becuase of 2 reasons, as far as I know:

1. The problem is with your `repositories` configuration section like here in gradle, or in your `<repositories>` Maven tag section.** It is just not correct, and build tool is receiving response, maybe not even an xml, and thus it is incapable to parse it.
2. It can be, that you have a corrupted local copy of the xml file. In this case, you can try to remove an offending file from local build cache (In case of maven it should be something like `.m2/repository/path/to/offending/file`) and execute build again.

It is hard to say what is wrong, each case is diffrent from one
another, but at least you now know where to dig. Good luck :)